# IE doesn't mark anchor links as visited correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am using in the CSS a:visited to mark visited links differently.

The links I am using are anchor links, in the form of #news33.

After clicking, the links are marked in IE with the correct color, but on reloading the page, the color is missing. This works perfectly fine with Chrome. Does anyone has an idea on what I should do?

Btw, I am using IE 10 on Windows 8.

I am posting some example code, where the problem can be seen in IE, which I adapted from the example of Twitter Bootstrap.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.css">
  <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
a:link { text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold; color:#e00000; }
a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:green; }
</style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $('#test').click(function(){
            $('#test222').click();
  });

});
    </script>
<!-- <a id="test2" href="http://www.commerzbank.de" data-toggle="modal">google</a> -->
<a id="test" href="#test222">Launch demo modal</a>
<a id="test222" href="#myModal2" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal 22</a> 
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

One important  thing to notice is that the link is used to display a modal, and the modal JS library is not following the link.

Thanks and best regards
Theo

Comment: Could be a cache problem?

Comment: Might be, but I also cleaned up the cache. Anything else I could do to see if there is something related to the cache? I also tried to put cache settings on always reload

Answer (score 0):

The CSS order matters with some browsers. I know with older versions of IE if you don't have the order of the rules correct the properties will not display as expected. I would hope IE10 would not still have this issue.

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}         /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}      /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}        /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}       /* selected link */
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: I am having the a selectors in my CSS file it in the order that first I have my 'a' selector, then a:visited. Should this work?

Comment: Your code is mostly okay, this appears to be a documented problem with IE. If you Google search something like "IE visited link color" you will see endless threads. Perhaps you can find an answer from Microsoft. You also have a SEC7115 error which you can fix by removing the text-decoration property from your visited properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180764(v=vs.85).aspx